# restrict users to access URL directly - spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security and there are no errors / exceptions, but it is not working, I am not able to redirect to the success page.
My success page is  **/sucessPage**,  **/Verify** will verifying the user details against database.
I want to verify the user with 3 different parameters

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name="AdminDB")
    private DataSource datasource; 
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Inside SecurityConfig - configure() - Spring security");
        security
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/unsecured/**", "/","/Verify").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/").permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    //.passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/sucessPage/")
                    .successHandler(successhandler())
                    .failureUrl("/")
                .and().logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/systemError.html")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successhandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

}
```

login page - HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="Form" action="#" th:action="@{/verify}" th:object="${Form}" method="post">
                
                    <div class="50">
                        <label for="first-name" class="label-first-name">First Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="first-name" placeholder="Enter First Name" th:field="*{firstName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="50">
                        <label for="last-name" class="label-last-name">Last Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last-name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" th:field="*{lastName}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="100">
                    <label for="email-1" class="label-email-address">Email Address*<span class="label-note">This is your login username</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" th:field="*{email}">
                </div>
                <div class="100">
                    <label for="email-2" class="label-email-address">Verify Email Address*</label>
                    <input type="text" id="verifyEmail" name="verifyEmail" placeholder="Re-enter Email" th:field="*{verifyEmail}">
                </div>
                <div class="100">
                    <label for="phone" class="label-phone-number">Phone Number<span class="label-note">(optional)</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" th:field="*{phoneNumber}">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Next">
            </form>
```

On submit it should verify user and redirect to the /sucessPage. I just want to restrict users to access other URLs directly and other flow will go as it is.
right now it's redirecting back to "/" without any error.

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginManager loginManager;
    

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        UserDetails user = null;
        try {
            user = loginManager.findUserByEmail(userName);
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

loadUserByUsername takes only 1 argument. I want to verify the user by firstName, lastName, email against db and redirecting to success with spring security.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think your SecurityConfig.java is incomplete

.formLogin().loginPage("/") is missing :

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
```

and

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/sucessPage")
```

Comment: .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll()
 .loginProcessingUrl("/verify")
 .usernameParameter("email")
 //.passwordParameter("password")
 .defaultSuccessUrl("/successPage/") Edited but no luck

Comment: hahaha you can downvote my answer all you want but still you were missing those 2 elements in your Security config, now if it still doesn't work it just means you also have other issues but  if you don't provide your whole configuration there is no way to guess where the issue is. And if you have provided it whole, you missed many, many things, i just recommand you follow online tutorials, like the one of Baeldung, they are complete and well explained. cheers, and keep downvoting people helping !

Comment: I updated the question, you can check now. the 2 elements are not mandatory. I am also trying, if found the solution I will post.